# Android EditText with only copy/select option

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want an `EditText` that only allows copy functionality, but does not allow editing of text inside it.
I'm using `TextInputEditText` here.

The scenario:
I have a form, which opens by default in a 'View only' mode. In this mode, all text is visible, but not editable.
When user selects 'Edit mode', form is displayed in edit mode.
In 'Edit mode', all text can be edited.

Things I have tried:
I have tried using `setInputType(InutType.TYPE_NULL)` and `setTextIsSelectable(true)`, but it does not work.
None of the `isFocusable`, `isClickable` combinations work either.
`setEnabled(false)` disables everything on the `EditText`, I want to keep the copy option.

I don't want to use a simple `TextView`, since the same text can be editable/non-editable and I need to use the provisions of `EditText` like **InputType**, **Password** toggle icon, error structure, etc.

Is there a way to toggle just the edit capabilities of `EditText`, without disabling the view completely?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `editText.setKeyListener(null)`, which seems to mostly stop the keyboard popping up (I get it if I select some text, but I can't edit it). Just remember to grab and store the `KeyListener` so you can set it back to re-enable things

Just FYI, you could also add an `InputFilter` implementation that overrides [#filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter?hl=en#filter(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20android.text.Spanned,%20int,%20int)) and just hands back the charsequence that's meant to be overwritten - so you're basically returning the original text unchanged. I think the KeyListener is nicer though

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
The key listener approach didn't work, everything still works as usual.The filter approach is a lengthier one, but I will try it too. I am just surprised there isn't a more straightforward way of doing this!